# How to write my name and my job description in a publication?

Tags: publications, teaching, affiliation

I'm a resident in a teaching hospital and not a staff member in a university, how to write my name and my job description in a publication as an author

Comment: I haven't seen job descriptions in publications, but in different fields that may be different.

Comment: By "job description", do you mean your affiliation?

Comment: yes my affiliation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write your affiliation similar to how you'll do it with a university.

> First Last 
> [Designation,] Dept., Institution

If your hospital does not split members into departments, then *Dept.* part can be omitted.

Examples:

*Aaron Stone 

Neurosurgeon, XYZ Clinic*

*Cathy Miller 

Researcher, Cancer Research Lab, BCD Hospital*

*Greg Thompson 

Cryogenics, GHI Health Institute*

Note that it is not always necessary to include your designation (job description), unless the publisher asks for it.

Comment: so this would be the possible form 
first last name
otolaryngology department, hospital name, city, country???

Comment: @AalaaElsadek Yes. The city and country may not be necessary in most cases.